# Display multiple Select statement results horizontally

Tags: sql, oracle

DB Version: Oracle 11.1.2.1.0
OS: OEL5

I am trying to print results of multiple SELECT statements horizontally using SQL, but not able to achieve my desired result.

Multiple SQLs:

```
SELECT 'DB Version', version db_version FROM v$instance
UNION ALL
select 'Oracle Client', length(addr)*4 || '-bits' word_length from v$process where ROWNUM =1
UNION ALL
/
```

Result:

```
'DBVERSION'            DB_VERSION  
 ---------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 DB Version             11.2.0.1.0  
 Oracle Client          64-bits
```

Desired Result:

```
DB VERSION  ORACLE CLIENT   
--------    ------------------ 
11.2.0.1.0  64-bits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is on way, assuming we're talking about the desired result being just one row with several columns:

```
select max(case when col = col1 then colval end) as "DB VERSION",
       max(case when col = col2 then colval end) as "ORACLE CLIENT"
  from (SELECT version colval, 'col1' col
          FROM v$instance
        UNION ALL
        select length(addr) * 4 || '-bits',
               'col2'
          from v$process
         where ROWNUM = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that each subquery returns one row, you can use `cross join` or subselects:

```
SELECT (SELECT version db_version FROM v$instance) as "DB Version",
       (select length(addr)*4 || '-bits' word_length from v$process where ROWNUM = 1) as "Oracle Client"
```

or:

```
SELECT v."DB Version", oc."Oracle Client"
FROM (SELECT version db_version as "DB Version" FROM v$instance) v CROSS JOIN
     (select length(addr)*4 || '-bits' as "Oracle Client" from v$process where ROWNUM = 1)  oc
```